# How to read array of dictionary from settings

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, asp.net-core

From appsettings.json i want to read this settings:

```
  "CountryPhoneSetting": [
    {
      "US": {
        "DialCode": "+1",
        "CanSMS": true,
        "CanVerify": true
      }
    }
  ]
```

This is the class in which i want to store it:

```
    public class CountryPhoneSetting
{
    public IDictionary<string, CountryDetails> CountryInfo {
        get;set;
    }

    public class CountryDetails
    {
        public string DialCode { get; set; }

        public bool CanSMS { get; set; }

        public bool CanVerify { get; set; }
    }
```

}

I have gone through stackoverflow solutions but none of them is working.

Please help

Comment: and i want to add it to services like:

services.Configure<CountryPhoneSetting>(Configuration.GetSection("CountryPhoneSetting"));

Comment: Show us the code that isn't working.

Comment: Configuration.GetSection("CountryPhoneSetting").GetChildren().ToList()
               .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value);

this results in empty

Comment: Weirdly the Json is "CountryPhoneSetting": **[**
    {
      "US": {
        "DialCode": "+1",
        "CanSMS": true,
        "CanVerify": true
      }
    }
 **]**, the extra `[]` makes it a `Dictionary<string, CountryPhoneSetting>[]` May you show a configuration with multiple entry in the dictionary.. Will it be multiple dictionary of one element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to change your json to:

```
"CountryPhoneSetting": {
    "CountryInfo": {
      "US": {
        "DialCode": "+1",
        "CanSMS": true,
        "CanVerify": true
      },
      "BR": {
        "DialCode": "+55",
        "CanSMS": true,
        "CanVerify": true
      }
    }
  }
```

And your class to:

```
public class CountryPhoneSetting
{
     public Dictionary<string, CountryDetails> CountryInfo { get; set; } = new Dictionary<string, CountryDetails>();

     public class CountryDetails
     {
        public string DialCode { get; set; }
        public bool CanSMS { get; set; }
        public bool CanVerify { get; set; }
     }
}
```

Usage:

```
Configuration.GetSection("CountryPhoneSetting").Bind(CountryPhoneSetting);
```

I've tested it, and it worked for me!

See: https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2017/dec/12/easy-configuration-binding-in-aspnet-core-revisited

Comment: I forgot to mention that to populate the object CountryPhoneSetting, you have to put this line of code inside Startup file: 
configuration.GetSection("CountryPhoneSetting").Bind(CountryPhoneSetting);

If you don't know how to do it, read this article: https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2017/dec/12/easy-configuration-binding-in-aspnet-core-revisited

Comment: This approach can be useful. Could you please update answer with your comment?

Comment: @SelimYıldız it seems that I don't have enough reputation to edit answers =( This is the first I'm aswering a question

Comment: the answer posted and the article that was shared helped me solve my problem.
thank you !

Answer (score 2):

I write small extension for my project. You can try it too

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace MyProject.Utilities
{
    public static class ConfigurationHelper
    {
        public static T Load<T> (this IConfiguration configuration, string section) where T : new()
        {
            if (typeof(T).IsValueType)
            {
                return LoadStruct<T>(configuration, section);
            }
            return LoadClass<T>(configuration, section);
        }   

        private static T LoadStruct<T>(IConfiguration configuration, string section)
        {
            return configuration.GetSection(section).Get<T>();
        }

        private static T LoadClass<T>(IConfiguration configuration, string section) where T:  new()
        {
            T variable = new T();
            configuration.GetSection(section).Bind(variable);
            return variable;
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
configuration.Load<List<CountryPhoneSetting>>("CountryPhoneSetting")
```

Edit: Reuired package - Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Binder

Also according to object in appsettings usage must be like this:

```
configuration.Load<List<Dictionary<string, CountryDetails>>>("CountryPhoneSetting")
```

Answer (score 0):

Notice the Extra `[]` after `CountryPhoneSetting`. It's an Array of dictionary.

```
public class CountryPhoneSetting
{
    [JsonProperty("CountryPhoneSetting")]
    public Dictionary<string, CountryDetails>[]  CountryInfo {get;set;}
}

public class CountryDetails
{
    [JsonProperty("DialCode")]
    public string DialCode { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("CanSMS")]
    public bool CanSms { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("CanVerify")]
    public bool CanVerify { get; set; }
}


var result  = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CountryPhoneSetting>(input);
```

will provide the expected behavior even if flattening the `Dictionary<string, CountryDetails>[]` into a `Dictionary<string, CountryDetails>` will not be easy without a clear definition of what to do with the duplicate key entry

[Live Demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/RkfH9k)